# Alchemy Settings : Alchemy Not Defined

Tags: gui-extensions, a4t

I'm trying to use the Alchemy Settings:

```
Alchemy.Plugins.MyPluginName.Api.getSettings()
```

As defined here: http://a4t-api.alchemywebstore.com/html/a155bb48-95ab-49c9-9b61-ebcc119dc2dd.htm

But in my plugin, I'm seeing the following error:

> "Alchemy Not Defined"

What have I missed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most likely if you are seeing the `Alchemy Not Defined` error message then you are missing the Alchemy WebAPI proxy from your resource group.

Within your resource group, just add the following invocation:

```
AddWebApiProxy();
```

This will ensure that the automatically generated JavaScript proxy is added as a file to your group.  This proxy not only contains the methods to communicate with any of your WebAPI controllers, but allows you to call the `getSettings()` method as well.

Hope that helps!